# What's better to use than a new thread for infinite loop working in background?

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

Right now, I'm reading outside application's memory in a new thread with a infinte loop

```
public void ReadMemory()
{
//read memory
Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Unfortunately, with even sleep of 1 ms, I can get 60-100 loops during 1 minute. Without any sleep, it's 1000-1500/sec loops but it takes much CPU. I can't believe there's nothing I can do with that so Im asking you here :P. CPU usage might be a problem because I'd like to add few more background-working functions in a different threads(or smth else)

is there anything that doesn't decrease ammount of loops like that with a pause of 10 ms?

Comment: Er, what exactly are you asking for? Code that runs without using CPU time? Your code either runs, or it doesn't (typically, if it's waiting for something). If it runs, then it... runs. Which means that it takes up CPU time. It's not really clear what you want your code to do.

Comment: is there anything that doesn't decrease ammount of loops like that with a pause of 10 ms?

Comment: For clarification:  I think what you're saying is that you want to read memory on a background thread, but you are having trouble throttling how often you read the memory; without a Thread.Sleep() you're getting 1000/1500 reads per second (too many, and too CPU intensive), but with the smallest sleep you can put in, Thread.Sleep(1) you're getting 60-100 (too few).  You want to get something between there, is that correct?

Comment: Of course a better design would be to avoid polling in the first place. Have the other application signal when it changes the thing you're interested in.

Comment: 1000-1500/sec with no sleep?  That's a mighty big chunk of memory being read from the other app - the one you do not mention - perhaps even all of it.  Why are you doing this?  It's the sort of thing that malware might do in an attempt to discover passwords during logon in the other app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about CPU usage. It's a nonsensical concept.

There's no such thing as "code that runs a little bit", or "running code slowly to only consume 25% CPU".

At the lowest level, it's a binary thing: your code either runs, consuming 100% of the core it runs on, or it doesn't, in which case it uses 0% CPU.

The CPU usage that the OS shows you is a running average.

So the question you need to ask is not "how do I run my code without using so much CPU", but the much simpler "does my code run when it shouldn't be running?" If you want your code to run, then it will, temporarily, at least, use 100% CPU, and there's nothing wrong with that.

It's not really clear what role the `Sleep()` call plays in your application.
What are you waiting for? Do you just want a few milliseconds to pass between each iteration? Or are you waiting for some specific event to occur?

In any case, when you call `Sleep(10)`, you are *not* suspending your thread for 10 milliseconds. You are suspending it for *at least* 10 milliseconds. You're telling the OS to put the thread into a sleep queue now, and once 10 ms have passed, the thread should be considered *eligible* to execute again. But that still depends on the OS getting around to scheduling your thread, which might take another 10ms (or more, or less, depending on a variety of factors)

On Windows, `Sleep(0)` is a special case, which you could experiment with. Instead of actually suspending your thread, it simply tells the OS that the thread is done with its current timeslice, allowing other threads/processes to execute, but without putting your thread to sleep: it's still eligible to be scheduled the next time a context switch occurs.
So if the goal is simply to ensure that other threads/processes get a chance to run, calling `Sleep(0)` might be a way to do it.

Another way is just to ignore the issue, and trust that the OS knows how to schedule processes (that is a pretty safe assumption. Don't worry about this unless you've actually *seen* that your other background processes are being starved. They most likely won't be).

And finally, of course, you can set thread and process priority, hinting to the OS at which threads it should prefer to schedule. If you give this thread a low priority, it will only be scheduled when no higher-prioritized thread is available, ensuring you won't starve out other threads.

Comment: [Why Sleep(1) is better than Sleep(0)](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,1c013d42-c983-4102-9233-ca54b8f3d1a1.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, but by the OP's own words, `Sleep(1)` apparently sleeps for too long. And the problems pointed out there only apply if the process has to wait for a lower-prioritized thread. So as long as that's not the case, I feel the option is worth pointing out, at least. Since we don't know exactly what the OP is after, I don't want to rule it out

Answer (score 1):

Threads are designed to consume as much CPU time as they can, *unless other threads need that CPU time.*  If you're just trying to release the thread so that the CPU can do other tasks, don't.  Windows will automatically allocate horsepower to any other threads, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than sleeping every iteration, what if you only do it occasionally.

Something like :

```
public class Reader
{
    private static int count= 0;

    public void ReadMemory()
    {
        //read memory

        // Sleep every 501 iterations
        if (Reader.count++ == 500)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            Reader.count  = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are running at about 1000 iterations a second and it takes 1 second to perform the switch then this will mean you will be running at full power for half-a-second, then throttle back for a second and then back to full power which will average out at 333 iterations per second.

Obviously you can try experimenting with values other than 500.